# Is there a way in Flurl.Http to get at Javascript?

Tags: c#, flurl

There is a site I am trying to login to with Flurl.Http, and I can successfully login. However, once you are logged in the site sets an access token on a url parameter and sets the `window.location` using this javascript:

```
function onStatusChange(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        window.location.replace('/login?accessToken='+response.authResponse.accessToken);
    }
  }
```

Is there anyway I can access the javascript `response` in order to grab the `accessToken`, because then I can just construct the Url and actually get to the authenticatecd content.

Comment: Flurl is an HTTP client, not a browser. You're asking for browser functionality, not HTTP client functionality.